# simple check box insertion into database using mysqli php

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I'm new to PHP. I learnt how to insert data from a textbox but I am facing a problem now when I have to get data from a checkbox. I checked out other posts but they are either too advanced and most of them are using mysql rather than mysqli.

I have 
->> two check boxes and a submit button

I would like insert the value of the check box into the database, when selected(one or both).

Thanks

HTML FORM Code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Insert Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> check box testing </h1>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="checkbox_test.php" >
<fieldset>
<legend> Checkbox Trial </legend> 

<h3> Subject selection </h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="PHP" value="php" id="cbsubp1"/> PHP 


<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ASP" value="course[]" id="cbsub2"/> ASP.NET 
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>

</fieldset>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and PHP code is

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Insert Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> check box testing </h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","chkbox");
//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Cannot connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "Connected to mySQL succesfully";
}

$query= "INSERT into sub(Subject1) VALUES('$_POST[php]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "record added";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $query= "INSERT into sub(Subject1) VALUES('{$_POST['php']}')";

Comment: Before using a value from GET, POST or COOKIE, you should check for existance: `if (isset($_POST['php']))` or you'd get a notice about an "undefined index"

Comment: Dont forget to learn prepared querys and validation along your journeys.

Comment: There is no field called `php` in your form.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code in accordance to the given comments above, to this

Comment: if(isset($_POST['php']))
{
$query= "INSERT into sub(Subject1) VALUES('{$_POST[php]}')";
mysqli_query($query);
echo "record added";
}

i get no error but nothing goes into the db

Comment: @YourCommonSense - does $_POST retrieve information from the value or the name attribute in a form?

Comment: it does it the same way which you learned when inserted data from a textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information:

If the checkbox is not selected on the form, the field is not sent in the posts array.
i.e. the actual fieldname $_POST['PHP'] will not exist.

You will need to change your code to something like this.

```
$subject1 = isset($_POST['php']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['php']) : 'DEFAULT_VALUE'; 

$query = "INSERT into sub(Subject1) VALUES('$subject1')";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if ( $result ) {
    echo 'Record Added';
} else {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

This will insert either the value of the checkbox field or your default value if the checkbox was not selected by the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot to every one who helped and thanks alot to @RiggsFolly

Comment: your given code worked well and worked with one check box ... :)